# How to access the Web using VBA? Please check my code

Tags: html, excel, vba

In order to improve the repeatitive work, I tried to access the Web site which is using in company using VBA.

So, I made code using VBA. And I checked it could be access the normal site such as google, youtube...
**But, I don't know why it could not be access the company site.**

VBA stopped this line
**`Set HTMLDoc = IE_ctrl.document`**

Thank you in advanced.

And I checked one different things(VBA Local values, type) between Normal and company site.
please check below 2 pictures.

```
Sub a()

Dim IE_ctrl As InternetExplorer
Dim HTMLDoc As HTMLDocument
Dim input_Data As IHTMLElement
Dim URL As String
URL = "https://www.google.com"

Set IE_ctrl = New InternetExplorer
IE_ctrl.Silent = True
IE_ctrl.Visible = True
IE_ctrl.navigate URL

Wait_Browser IE_ctrl

Set HTMLDoc = IE_ctrl.document

Wait_Browser IE_ctrl

Set input_Data = HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("text").Item
input_Data.Click

End Sub
```

```
Sub Wait_Browser(Browser As InternetExplorer, Optional t As Integer = 1)
 
While Browser.Busy
DoEvents
Wend

Application.Wait DateAdd("s", t, Now)
 
End Sub
```

1. Normal site(operating well.)
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHbzg.png)
2. Company site(operating error.)
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWQt5.png)

Comment: The `IE_control` value for google is `InternetExplorer/WebBrowser2`, but for your site it is just `InternetExplorer`. I don't know what that means exactly. First thought is, make sure you `Set` objects to `Nothing` when you're done with them. Maybe that will help when they are reset for the next website. Also make sure the URL is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following code. Please read the comments. I can't say anymore because I don't know the page or the html of the page.

```
Sub a()

'Use late binding for what you need
Dim ie As Object
Dim nodeInputData As Object
Dim url As String

  url = "https://www.google.com"
  
  'Use the windows GUID to initialize the Internet Explorer, if you
  'want to get access to a company page. This helps if there are
  'security rules you can't access over other ways of initializing IE
  'This don't work in most cases for pages in the "real" web
  'Read here for more infos:
  'https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ieinternals/2011/08/03/default-integrity-level-and-automation/
  Set ie = GetObject("new:{D5E8041D-920F-45e9-B8FB-B1DEB82C6E5E}")
  ie.Visible = True
  ie.navigate url
  'Waiting for the document to load
  Do Until ie.readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
  'If necessary, if there is dynamic content that must be loaded,
  'after the ie reports, loading was ready
  '(The last three values are: hours, minutes, seconds)
  Application.Wait (Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1))
  
  'I don't know your html. If you only want to click a button,
  'you don't need a varable
  'ie.document.getElementsByClassName("text")(0).Click
  'will do the same like
  Set nodeInputData = ie.document.getElementsByClassName("text")(0)
  nodeInputData.Click
  
  'A short explanation of getElementsByClassName() and getElementsByTagName():
  'Both methods create a node collection of all html elements that was found
  'by the creteria in the brackets. This is because there can be any number of
  'html elements with specified class names or tag names. If, for example,
  '3 html elements with the class name "Text" were found, a node collection
  'with three elements is created by getElementsByClassName("Text").
  'These have the indices 0 to 2, as in an array. The individual elements are
  'also addressed via these indices. They are indicated in round brackets.
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for reply.
but I tried that, there is some error.
<ie.document> macro can not detect this comment.